# pgfplots: how to bring all node plot annotations to top in proper way?

Tags: pgfplots, labels, nodes, pgflayers

I'm plotting many almost parallel lines (in the MWE I'm just plotting random stuff), where I am using the very convenient `node[pos=0.x]{label}` option to annotate my graph.

The issue is, that multiple lines run so closely to each other that the following plot curves obstruct my label (just so slightly, but still ugly). I am therefore looking for an option to plot all nodes after the curves have been drawn. I'm not quite sure how to do this, except for plotting the graphs first and then doing a phantom curve (with `opacity=0` on top which will then contain the annotation nodes).

**How to do this properly?**

PS in the MWE, an easy solution would be to shift the annotation. In my actual case, many lines run almost parallel, so that is not a solution.

'Normal' output (note the ugly 'x'):

[image: Label obstructed by plot]

Desired output (here done by plotting graphs 'twice'):

[image: Label not obstructed by plot]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[]{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{
compat=newest,
cycle list/Set1,
width=6cm,
height=6cm
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[myannotation/.style={font=\tiny,fill=white,rounded corners=2pt,fill opacity=1,inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt}]
    \begin{axis}[thick,smooth]
      \addplot+[] {x^3}node[myannotation,pos=0.3]{$x^3$};
      \addplot+[] {x}node[myannotation,pos=0.35]{$x$};
      \addplot+[] {x^2}node[myannotation,pos=0.3]{$x^2$};

      %uncomment following lines for desired version.
      \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-3};
      \addplot+[opacity=0] {x^3}node[myannotation,pos=0.3]{$x^3$};
      \addplot+[opacity=0] {x}node[myannotation,pos=0.35]{$x$};
      \addplot+[opacity=0] {x^2}node[myannotation,pos=0.3]{$x^2$};
      
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better just to move the nodes to better locations?

Comment: @John, as pointed out in the question, in this MWE, moving the nodes is indeed the better choice. However, in my actual use case that is not really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution.  In fact, it is generally better to move annotation out of the axis environment.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[]{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{
compat=newest,
cycle list/Set1,
width=6cm,
height=6cm
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[myannotation/.style={font=\tiny,fill=white,rounded corners=2pt,fill opacity=1,inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt}]
    \begin{axis}[thick,smooth]
      \addplot+[] {x*x*x} coordinate[pos=0.3] (A);
      \addplot+[] {x} coordinate[pos=0.35] (B);
      \addplot+[] {x*x} coordinate[pos=0.3] (C);
    \end{axis}
    \node[myannotation,text=Set1-A] at (A) {$x^3$};
    \node[myannotation,text=Set1-B] at (B) {$x$};
    \node[myannotation,text=Set1-C] at (C) {$x^2$};
    %\foreach \c/\d in{A/$x^3$, B/$x$, C/$x^2$} {\node[myannotation,text={Set1-\c}] at(\c) {\d};}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe even shorter to do `\foreach \loc/\text in {A/$x$,B/$x^2$,C/$x^3$}{\node[myannotation] at (\loc){\text};}`

Comment: Issue with this solution is however, that the colors of the annotation are all black and do not obey the corresponding cycle list. So I would need have to manually assign the colors \Set1-A etc. Ok for 3 but tedious for a large number.

Comment: The time needed to debug loops is often greater than the time needed to copy/paste and edit.